# How to populate my fact table with Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, kettle, datamart

I want to load data from a csv file containing many columns using PDI to the data mart that I designed and implemented on SQL Server, and I don't know how can I load the foreign keys of the dimensions into my fact table, can you give me an idea about how to acheive my goal?

Here is the star schema of my data mart :

[image]

and the csv file containing the raw data is composed by all the columns of the dimensions together except the primary keys, and the column contained in the fact : handling_time is also present in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you find your answer? This task is one of the must common tasks on data warehousing and its applied in every tool you use, the recomended approach is by using "lookups" where for every transaction in your data source you perform a lookup (key value search) to your dimension tables, where the key its the identifier(s) in the transactional data source and the value its the surrogate key in the dimension table.